# MySQL how to group values not specified in the WHERE clause as "others"?

Tags: mysql, group-by, where-clause

I need to produce a statistical report of the site visits. In the report users can specify various parameters. So far, whenever they select values for a parameter, an additional WHERE clause is added, like this:

```
SELECT id_browser, COUNT(visits)
FROM table
WHERE [...] 
AND id_browser IN (1, 3, 6)
GROUP BY id_browser
```

But what I really need to do is to show the statistics for the remaining browsers as well, but I need to group them together as "other browsers". How can I do this?

Comment: You can't, because those other records have been excluded by your WHERE clause.

Comment: could you provide output what you want... is it like FF, IE, Chrome, Others ??

Comment: Marc, I was wondering if I can modify the WHERE clause somehow, so that it treats any other value as a constant. I know this won't work but what I'm looking for is something like this: 

WHERE (id_browser IN (1, 3, 6) OR (id_broswer NOT IN (1, 3, 6) AS -1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below  :

```
    SELECT id_browser, 
    count(if(id_browser IN (1, 3, 6),1,0)) as 136browser,
    count(if(id_browser Not IN (1, 3, 6),1,0)) as other_browser
    FROM table
    WHERE [...] 
    GROUP BY id_browser
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I did not exactly use this, but it made me think and in the end I rewrote my query like this: 

SELECT IF(id_browser NOT IN (1, 3, 6), -1, id_browser) AS id_browser, COUNT(visits)
FROM table
WHERE [...] 
AND IF(id_browser NOT IN (1, 3, 6), -1, id_browser) IN (1, 3, 6, -1)
GROUP BY id_browser

Answer (score 1):

Use `CASE` syntax:

e.g.,

```
SELECT CASE
           WHEN id_browser = 1 THEN 'IE'      -- I am just inventing
           WHEN id_browser = 3 THEN 'Chrome'  -- some mappings
           WHEN id_browser = 6 THEN 'Firefox' -- for these
           ELSE 'All Other Browsers'
       END
       ,COUNT(visits)
 FROM [table]
WHERE [...] 
GROUP BY CASE
           WHEN id_browser = 1 THEN 'IE'
           WHEN id_browser = 3 THEN 'Chrome'
           WHEN id_browser = 6 THEN 'Firefox'
           ELSE 'All Other Browsers'
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unite the results using `UNION`

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT id_browser, COUNT(visits)
    FROM table
    WHERE [...] 
    AND id_browser IN (1, 3, 6)
    GROUP BY id_browser
         UNION
    SELECT 'Other Browser' as id_browser, COUNT(visits)
    FROM table
    WHERE [...] 
    AND id_browser NOT IN (1, 3, 6)
) AllResult
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it is a simple union:

```
select id_browser, count(visits) from table
where [...] and id_browser in (1, 3, 6)
group by id_browser
union
select 'Other browsers', count(visits) from table
where [...] and id_browser not in (1, 3, 6)
group by id_browser
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

SELECT 
   SUM( CASE WHEN id_browser =1 then 1 else 0 ) AS IE
   SUM( CASE WHEN id_browser =2 then 1 else 0 ) AS FIREFOX
   SUM( CASE WHEN id_browser =3 then 1 else 0 ) AS CHROME
   SUM( CASE WHEN id_browser not in (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 ) AS OTHERS
FROM tableName
```